# Check if product bundle has bundle-upsells ( optional items ) or simple bundled items

Tags: php, woocommerce, find, bundle, product

I am pretty new to coding and trying to edit our WC website a bit.
Hope my English is decent enough to pass the needed information…

I made a function that checks if product is a type- bundle and it works fine.
Unfortunately, I need my function to differ between bundles with optional items and bundles without optional bundled items.

--
Edited update: I changed my tactics, since I dont need JS for this check.
But, I lack the needed php basics anyways.

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'ino_qty_main_function');

    function ino_qty_main_function() {
        global $product;
        if ( $product->is_type('bundle') ) {
            $hasqty = 5;
                $bundleditems = $product->get_bundled_items();
                foreach ( $bundled_items as $bundleditem ) {
                    if ( $bundleditem->is_optional('yes')) {
                        $hasqty = 1;
                        echo "<h2> 1 product optional </h2>";
                    } else {
                        $hasqty = 0;
                        echo "<h2> 1 product not optional </h2>";
                    }
                }
            echo "<h2> final hasqty" . $hasqty . "</h2>";
        }

    }
```

this is a function to check how it works [ Not working with IDE, working on staging site ].
I am pretty sure I lack the basic knowledge on how to perform this check.

in the bundle plugin files i found the next things that should help to build this function correctly:

```
public function is_optional() {
        return 'yes' === $this->optional;
    }
```

and also the array that stores the data:

```
private function load_data() {

        // Defaults.
        $defaults = array(
            'quantity_min'                          => 1,
            'quantity_max'                          => 1,
            'quantity_default'                      => 1,
            'priced_individually'                   => 'no',
            'shipped_individually'                  => 'no',
            'override_title'                        => 'no',
            'title'                                 => '',
            'override_description'                  => 'no',
            'description'                           => '',
            'optional'                              => 'no',
            'hide_thumbnail'                        => 'no',
            'discount'                              => '',
            'override_variations'                   => 'no',
            'override_default_variation_attributes' => 'no',
            'allowed_variations'                    => false,
            'default_variation_attributes'          => false,
            'single_product_visibility'             => 'visible',
            'cart_visibility'                       => 'visible',
            'order_visibility'                      => 'visible',
            'single_product_price_visibility'       => 'visible',
            'cart_price_visibility'                 => 'visible',
            'order_price_visibility'                => 'visible',
            'stock_status'                          => null,
            'max_stock'                             => null
        );
```

What I want to achieve is to check if the product page has bundled items, if it does - to check if at least one of the bundled products is optional.
if it is, $hasqty = 1 , else $hasqty=0.

Edit2:
Got it to work! And realized I missed a lot of the basics.

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'ino_qty_main_function');

    function ino_qty_main_function() {
        global $product;
        if ( $product->is_type('bundle') ) {
            $hasqty = 0;
                $bundleditems = $product->get_bundled_items();
                foreach ( $bundleditems as $bundleditem ) {
                    if ($bundleditem->is_optional('yes')) {
                
                        $hasqty++ ;
                        echo "<h2> 1 product optional </h2>";
                    }
                }
        
            echo "<h2> final hasqty" . $hasqty . "</h2>";
        }
    }
```

All that's left is to tweak it to add buttons instead of printing the testing values.

Comment: $product->get_upsell_ids(); will give you the ids of upsell products (if have any) is that what you are looking for ? If not try debuging the product object and see what data is having and go from there.

Comment: I guess it should work.
Trying to work mostly on CSS since I lack the knowledge for PHP and JS and help myself out with snippets.

If it is indeed the one I need, how do I turn $product->get_upsell_ids() into : "if product retrieved upsell_ids, add button B, if product retrieved none, do nothing ?
If It's okay to ask for it.

P.s - the upsells I talk are a special feature of the WC bundle plugin, adding upsells that can added to cart directly on current product page. Hope it gets only those and not all of the linked items.

Comment: If its plugin feature then this wont help. So your best bet is either debug product object debug(print_r($product,true)); (you must enable debug https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/debug/debug-wordpress/ ) and share it in your question or ask support of the plugin since its premium.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'ino_qty_main_function');

    function ino_qty_main_function() {
        global $product;
        if ( $product->is_type('bundle') ) {
            $hasqty = 0;
                $bundleditems = $product->get_bundled_items();
                foreach ( $bundleditems as $bundleditem ) {
                    if ($bundleditem->is_optional('yes')) {
                
                        $hasqty++ ;
                        echo "<h2> 1 product optional </h2>";
                    }
                }
        
            echo "<h2> final hasqty" . $hasqty . "</h2>";
        }
    }
```

Counts the optional bundled items!
Since we are going to use only Simple Bundles or only Optional Bundles - It's enough for me to keep going with rest of the code.

Hope it might also help someone in the future.
Works with WooCommerce bundles plugin